# Splited string of cookie is not working

Tags: javascript

Considering this is the HTML code,

```js
function changeColor(){
       var selectedColor = document.getElementById("selectColor").value;
       if(selectedColor != "selectTheColor"){
          document.bgColor = selectedColor;
          document.cookie = "color="+selectedColor+";expires=Fri, 2 Mar 2018 02:00:00 UTC";
          var splited = document.cookie.split("="); // codes here not working
          alert(splited[1]);
       }
    }
```

```html
<select value="bgColor" id="selectColor" onchange="changeColor();">
          <option value="selectTheColor">Select color</option>
          <option value="black">Black</option>
          <option value="blue">Blue</option>
          <option value="red">Red</option>
    </select>
```

why is the code not working on the split?

Comment: Your code works fine if the next line of the value is pulled in just one line. I hope this is just for formatting here in the post. Otherwise, you would have got syntax error which is not mentioned..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assigning a string over more that one line is not supported this way (using '', you have to use ` ` instead). Do the following instead:

```js
function changeColor(){
   var selectedColor = document.getElementById("selectColor").value;
   if(selectedColor != "selectTheColor"){
      document.bgColor = selectedColor;
      var test = "color="+selectedColor+`;expires=Fri, 2 Mar 2018 
      02:00:00 UTC`;
      var splited = test.split("="); // codes here not working
      alert(splited[1]);
   }
}
```

```html
<select value="bgColor" id="selectColor" onchange="changeColor();">
      <option value="selectTheColor">Select color</option>
      <option value="black">Black</option>
      <option value="blue">Blue</option>
      <option value="red">Red</option>
</select>
```

Comment: OP has entered the code in next line here in the post to format it properly.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal hm, maybe you are right. But the alert does post the `splited[1]` so i guess OP will be happy :D

Comment: Otherwise OP would have get syntax error. But he didn't mentioned.

Comment: yes and the syntax error occures when executing his code: https://jsfiddle.net/6asrerw1/ (have a look in the console)

Comment: That's why this answer is not valid as he was saying `undefined` result.

Comment: The answer is valid due to the wanted result is showing

Comment: NO. Consider closing the question as a simple typo.

Comment: and i guess it is not my job to think about any mistakes the OP did while posting....i read his problem and i solve it...

Comment: not blaming you... but we should not consider answering on those typo...